# How should I finger this on piano?

Tags: piano, fingering

I am an experienced composer with moderate piano skill.  I've only taken a handful of piano lessons.  My limited piano skills usually suffice to get me through playing what I need to as I compose.  A particular bass figure has me stumped, though.

[image]

I'd like to be able to play this figure with my left hand at a decent tempo (q=120 or faster), but I keep stumbling over my fingers.  The figure begins A-minor-ish for a beat  then shifts to C-minor-ish, and then it repeats.  (Or you could view it as most of an octatonic scale.)  I can play the first beat by itself, and the second beat by itself.
But how do I bridge the two beats together?  The second bar (after the repeat) returns to white keys, which is much easier.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I’d suggest something like this:

[image]

This is quite comfortable to play and can be played quite fast, and the transition between measure 1 and measure 2 is really nice two (as the first pattern ends on 2 and the second starts on 1). This would look something like this (the position is a bit awkward: as I’m trying to play while holding my phone ...):

Answer (score 2):

Beginner pianists are often given blanket advice to avoid thumb on black keys, but for an ostinato like this is would definitely go with 4321 4321. (Unless this is *all* you have to play, in that case I would simply sit farther to the left and go 2123 1234 with my right hand!)

Comment: Or - 1st 4 l.h., 2nd 4 r.h., etc..?

Comment: If it were all I had to play, I would definitely two-hand it!  Alas, the right hand is busy, too :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try 4321 4321 4321 5432 1231 2345 1231 2345.